# Isn't "tapping" what you say when you fill up a bath tub with water?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-usage

> I'm going to tap the tub.

This apparently makes no sense, according to a native English girl.

I was baffled, and made many searches online for "tapping a bath" and "tap a bath", etc. Found nothing.

I looked up "tap" and "tapping" but no meaning was related to "tapping a bath".

Have I just got this into my head for some random reason? I always thought that in English, you "tap a bath" by making the water come out from the tap at the bath tub in order to fill it up; you "tap the bath".

Is this not how you say it? If so, what is the correct term for "tapping" a bath?

Comment: Someone said, run a bath. That's right. You run a bath by turning on the faucet.

Comment: @Lambie ... You don't do  it by turning on the tap?

Comment: I've never heard "tapping" used in this sense in the US.

Comment: @GEdgar turn on the tap or faucet, same thing. But the idiom is: to run a bath.

Comment: Source of the quote, and a longer quote for context, please.  What kind of tub? Is it clear that it's a bathtub?     "Tapping a barrel" means that you insert a tap in order to draw some beer to drink.  Depending on context, it might mean something similar.

Comment: I have never heard of this expression in the UK either.

Comment: The verb _tap_ (or "tap a bath") is not used to fill a bathtub with water; however, _OED_ includes these somewhat related senses where the confusion might be coming from: "To draw (liquor) from a tap", "To draw off (liquid) from any source."

Comment: _Draw a bath, run a bath, take a bath_ are all idiomatic phrases. _Tap_ with a liquiferous direct object means to remove liquid, not to insert it. It might be a mishearing of _take_, though the vowels are different.

Comment: I draw a bath -- but that's not the only option. / Maybe *tap* is a regionalism.

Answer (score 4):

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+a+bath) shows an idiom:

> **run a bath**
> To fill a bathtub with water before bathing.

As a native English speaker, I have never heard "tap the tub" or "tapping a bath".

Comment: _Draw a bath_ is used also, although dated.

Answer (score 3):

"Tap" is a noun referring to a device that allows liquid flow to be controlled. It can be described as a combination spout and valve. As a verb, you "tap" a barrel or keg by inserting a tap in an opening.

So, you can fill a bathtub, or "run a bath," by opening a tap (faucet). But you would not "tap a tub," unless you are inserting a tap into the tub, maybe as a drain.